# Regge trajectory and Kaluza Klein tower

Tags: mass, quantization, kaluza-klein, mesons

The mass of hadrons in the Regge trajectory scales as

$m=\sqrt{\frac{J}{\alpha}-\alpha_0}=\sqrt{\frac{n}{\alpha}-\alpha_0}\propto \sqrt{n}$,

where $J=n$ is the spin of the particle (in natural units, for zero angular momentum) and $\alpha$ is the inverse QCD string tension.

In the Kaluza Klein (KK) model, the mass scales as

$m=\frac{n}{R}\propto n$

where $R$ is the radius of the KK compactified dimension.

Can we obtain any relation between these two mass formulas, perhaps yielding a relation between the KK radius $R$ and the inverse string tension $\alpha$ in the Regge trajectory?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. In the first formula, $n$ is related to spin/angular momentum. In the second formula, it just labels the $n$-th scalar in the Kaluza-Klein tower. There's no related between the two $n$, so what's the question?

Comment: What "number of fermion"? The Kaluza-Klein states are scalars, their spin is known. Also, Regge trajectories are relations for *resonance states*, I have no idea where you see the connection to the mass of a free particle state such as the Kaluza-Klein states.

Comment: Is there really no possible connection between the masses? Can't the resonance states be described as elementary free particles at some specific energy scale?

Comment: there is a connection between string theory and Regge poles,https://books.google.gr/books?id=c43kBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA556&lpg=PA556&dq=regge+poles++and+string+theory&source=bl&ots=pGUJh8QCaD&sig=GWvwpSgKIuejwFl2l-lb0YgLH5c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDYQ6AEwA2oVChMI-6q6tIDyyAIVxtQaCh3njgha#v=onepage&q=regge%20poles%20%20and%20string%20theory&f=false , and between string theory and kaluza klein http://www.superstringtheory.com/experm/exper5a1.html . Maybe you can extrapolate to a connection between KK and Regge

Comment: see also this post here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13728/what-are-the-details-around-the-origin-of-the-string-theory

Comment: This link was extremely useful, http://www.superstringtheory.com/experm/exper5a1.html, thanks for that, Anna! But I still haven't found a connection to the Regge trajectory...